# How do I split string value with Regex expression and return an array and object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Input**: `Hi #[Pill(google.0.LastName)], How is going #[Pill(google.0.FirstName)]?`

this **Input** has regex expression of `const pillRegex = /#\[dataPill\((.*)\)\]/i;`

`#[Pill(google.0.LastName)]` and `#[Pill(google.0.LastName)]` are the matching results.

I want to build an array with objects and indicate if the value is matched or not. (If you have better data structure, you can use it)

```
[
   {
      pill: false, //not matched
      svalue: 'Hi ' //value
   }, {
      pill: true, //matching regex
      svalue: ["google", "0", "Last Name"]] //the value

   },
   ...
]
```

Comment: I think you’re going to need to explain yourself a little better, because I have no idea what you want.

Comment: Ok I'm editing it now

Comment: @RobertClarke Did it help?

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you mean. I guess you could split the string on each space character, so you have each word on its own in an array. Then you could loop through the array and check each string, to see if it matches the regex. Then push the relevant data to the output array as your iterate through the array of words. Hopefully that makes some sense

Comment: Could you provide an example code? "push the relevant data to the array as your iterate through the array" <- This part doesn't make sense but it will be easy to verify it with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here’s my second answer to your problem. This time I’m splitting it on the regex.

```js
var input = “Hi #[Pill(google.0.LastName)], How is going #[Pill(google.0.FirstName)]?”;

const regex = new RegExp(/#\[Pill\([A-Za-z0-9]+\.\d\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\)\]/);

input = input.split(/(#\[Pill\([A-Za-z0-9]+\.\d\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\)\])/g);

output = [];

input.forEach(word => {
    temp = {
        pill: regex.test(word),
        svalue: word + “ “
    };
    output.push(temp);
});

console.dir(output);
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "pill": false,
    "svalue": "Hi  "
  },
  {
    "pill": true,
    "svalue": "#[Pill(google.0.LastName)] "
  },
  {
    "pill": false,
    "svalue": ", How is going  "
  },
  {
    "pill": true,
    "svalue": "#[Pill(google.0.FirstName)] "
  },
  {
    "pill": false,
    "svalue": "? "
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay here is some code I wrote, that I think achieves what you’re looking for:

```js
var input = “Hi #[Pill(google.0.LastName)], How is going #[Pill(google.0.FirstName)]?”;

const regex = new RegExp(/#\[Pill\(google\.\d\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\)\]/);

input = input.split(“ “);

output = [];

input.forEach(word => {
    temp = {
        pill: regex.test(word),
        svalue: word + “ “
    };
    output.push(temp);
});

console.dir(output);
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "pill": false,
    "svalue": "Hi"
  },
  {
    "pill": true,
    "svalue": "#[Pill(google.0.LastName)],"
  },
  {
    "pill": false,
    "svalue": "How"
  },
  {
    "pill": false,
    "svalue": "is"
  },
  {
    "pill": false,
    "svalue": "going"
  },
  {
    "pill": true,
    "svalue": "#[Pill(google.0.FirstName)]?"
  }
]
```

Comment: Sorry, not quite. the first element should contain empty space end of it. ex) `"Hi "`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163128/regex-is-not-returning-multiple-matches?noredirect=1#comment111693146_63163128

Comment: Maybe this explains better.

Comment: I’ve edited my answer, and since we’re splitting the string on every space, in the foreach loop I’ve just added a space back on again.

Comment: Did you also need to have an array, split on each `.` if the text does match the regex?

Comment: Okay based on your other question thread, I’m going to write a new answer