# Regex is not returning multiple matches

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my Regex pattern.

```
const dataPillRegex = /#\[dataPill\((.*)\)\]/g;
```

with value (Singular match), it prints the right array,
But with value2 (multiple matches), it returns a wrong result.

```
value = "Hi #[dataPill(salesforce.0.LastName)], ?"
const splitedValue2 = value2.split(dataPillRegex); //['Hi ', 'salesforce.0.LastName', ', ?']

value2 = "Hi #[dataPill(salesforce.0.LastName)], How is going #[dataPill(salesforce.0.FirstName)]?"
const splitedValue2 = value.split(dataPillRegex); 
//['Hi ', 'salesforce.0.LastName)], How is going #[dataPill(salesforce.0.FirstName', ', ?']
```

splitedValue2 should be...

```
//['Hi ', 'salesforce.0.LastName', ', How is going ', 'salesforce.0.FirstName', ', ?']
```

Furthermore,,, It will be awesome if I can have want to have,,,

```
[
    'Hi ',
    '#[dataPill(salesforce.0.LastName)]',
    ', How is going ',
    '#[dataPill(salesforce.0.FirstName)]',
    '?'
]
```

Comment: how are value and value2 different?

Comment: Thanks I just edited the post

Comment: This might be a super difficult problem

Comment: make it not as greedy: `/#\[dataPill\((.*?)\)\]/g;`  (added '?')... also fix your example: `splitedValue2 = value2.` you can use the /./.exec() method to harvest stats about particular matches.

Comment: Still showing the long element in codespace :( `salesforce.0.LastName)], How is going #[dataPill(salesforce.0.FirstName`

Comment: i get `["Hi ", "salesforce.0.LastName", ", How is going ", "salesforce.0.FirstName", "?"]`, which seems to me what you're looking for...

Comment: Could you please add a query or something to get the final result?

Comment: How do I convert it to `[
    {value: 'Hi ', matched: false},
    {value: 'salesforce.0.LastName', matched: true'},
    {value: ', How is going ', matched: false}, 
    {value: 'salesforce.0.FirstName': matched: true,
    {value: ', ?', matched: false]
}
 ` Is it another problem?

Comment: You can just post your answer. It will be helpful for many people I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s my answer, from your duplicate question.

```js
var input = ”Hi #[dataPill(salesforce.0.LastName)], ?”;

const regex = new RegExp(/#\[dataPill\([A-Za-z0-9]+\.\d\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\)\]/);

input = input.split(/(#\[dataPill\([A-Za-z0-9]+\.\d\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\)\])/g);

output = [];

input.forEach(word => {
    temp = {
        value: word + “ “,
        matched: regex.test(word)
    };
    output.push(temp);
});

console.dir(output);
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "value": "Hi  ",
    "matched": false
  },
  {
    "value": "#[dataPill(salesforce.0.LastName)] ",
    "matched": true
  },
  {
    "value": ", ? ",
    "matched": false
  }
]
```

Comment: Accepted. Can you work on this tooo? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63164192/how-to-get-matching-regex-content-in-javascript