# How to get matching Regex content in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Given the string,
#[pill(hello.0.LastName)]

How do I get `hello.0.LastName`?

Here is Regex Pattern:
`const dataPillRegex = /#\[hello\((.*?)\)\]/g;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a solution, `output` is an array with various different pieces of information in it, but the only piece you need is `output[1]`. Nevertheless, I would still recommend logging the whole of `output` to the console so you can see what’s in there.

```js
const input = "#[pill(hello.0.LastName)]";
output = input.match(/#\[pill\((.+)\)\]/);
console.log(output[1]);
```

Output:

```
hello.0.LastName
```

You could also add a `g` to the end of the regex string if you don’t want the excess data:

```js
const input = "#[pill(hello.0.LastName)]";
output = input.match(/#\[pill\((.+)\)\]/g);
console.log(output[0]);
```

Output:

```
hello.0.LastName
```